# how to return a count value with sqllite and c#

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

I am trying to see if a record exists using c# and sqllite..

My code is as follows

```
  public static bool RecordExists(string fileName)
        {
            SetConnection();
            bool returnValue = false;

            try
            {
                using (SQLiteCommand sqlCommand = new SQLiteCommand("select count(FileName) from downloadedfiles where fileName = '@Filename'", sql_con))
                {
                    sql_con.Open();
                   sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@FileName", fileName));
                   long userCount = (long)sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
                    if (userCount > 0)
                    {
                        returnValue = true;
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }    


            return returnValue;
        }
```

Two things,

first point - Originally I had my userCount as int, but it kept saying cast error... why would it have been doing that?

Second point -  userCount always returns 0, even when there is data with the same fileName in the table..

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `Int32 userCount = (Int32)sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();`? Because select count returns a integer type.

Comment: same issue.. says case error... I have installed the 64bit sqllite.. would that cause an issue?

Comment: Maybe your query returns `null` and cannot be converted to long. Try `Convert.ToLong(sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar());`

Comment: sorry you must have misunderstood me... long works fine... I was wondering why int or int 32 doesn't work?

Comment: Ah I see. Maybe you already tried `Convert.ToInt32`, if also returns a cast error or a count of 0 maybe your passing a wrong parameter? You already try this? `Add(new SQLiteParameter("@FileName", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = fileName);`

Comment: What do you mean with "second userCount"?

Comment: CL - i updated my question to clarify-- see above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select count(FileName) 
from downloadedfiles 
where fileName = '@Filename'
'@Filename'=>@Filename
```

Comment: The OP is facing a different issue

Comment: Thanks xsami - This fixed the issue of me not returning zero all the time

Answer (score 0):

1st you should not use quotes in parameter. 2nd you name the parameter @Filename in your query where as you use `@FileName` when you add it. Those 2 have as result your query to always return null. Try:

```
using (SQLiteCommand sqlCommand = new SQLiteCommand("select count(FileName) from downloadedfiles where fileName = @Filename", sql_con))
{
  sql_con.Open();
  sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter("@Filename", fileName));
  int userCount = (int)sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar();
  if (userCount > 0)
  {
     returnValue = true;
  }
}
```